# How to apply a filter on a subscription?

Tags: angular

I have a subscription that returns a list of objects of type fruit let say:

```
class Fruit {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}
```

and I have a observable in my component like so:

```
fruitsStream$: Observable<Fruit[]>;
fruitList = Fruit[];
```

This observable receives data so:

```
this.fruitsStream$ = this.FruitService.getFruits();
this.fruitsStream$.subscribe(x => this.fruitList = x);
```

In my view I have a set of checkboxes for colors e.g. check box for red, one for yellow and one for green. These check boxes are 2-way bound to an color filter in the component:

```
colorFilter: { [color: string]: boolean } = {};
```

and as colors are toggled they are added or removed from a set

```
filterColorSet = new Set<string>()
```

How can I do a *ngFor loop that only shows the fruits where the color is checked. OR all colors if none or all are checked.

Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitList" *ng-if="fruitFilter.some(filterColorSet)">
```

There must be an easier way to do this.. I hope.

### Thanks in advance

EDIT 1

Based on suggestions to use a fitler before the subscribe, I have changed it to the code below. I think I am close.. but not yet working. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
if (clrs.length === 0) {
    clrs = this.allColors;
}
let clrFilt: Set<string> = new Set(clrs);
this.fStrm$ = this.FruitService.getFruits();
this.fStrm$
    .flatMap(fruits => {
        let filtered = new Array();
        fruits.forEach(fruit => {
            if (fruit.color.some(clr => clrFilt.has(clr))) {
                filtered.push(fruit);
            }
        });
        return Observable.create(function (obs) {
            obs.onNext(filtered);
            obs.onComplete();
        });
    })
    .subscribe(function (elem) {
        this.allfStrm = elem;
    });
```

Comment: The `Fruit` class has `color` property which is string. Could you give example of `Fruit` object which has all colors checked?

Comment: AS fruit has only one color. But I might be want to create a filter that shows only red and yellow fruit.
This filter I store as a set of string that gets updated when the user selects a new color

Comment: Why don't you filter the stream (with `filter`) **before** subscribing to it?